# Dropdown menu became undefine if I click the menu item

Tags: javascript, html

------HTML code--------

```
<div>
    <p id="selectText">All Categories</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="options">A</li>
        <li class="options">B</li>
        <li class="options">C</li>
        <li class="options">D</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

------JS code-------------

```
const options = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
const selectText = document.getElementById("selectText");

for (option of options) {
    option.onclick = () => {
        selectText.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

I tried to change my dropdown menu name "All categories"
to the menu item I clicked (A, B, ...)

But all I got was undefined :(

I guessed there's something wrong with "this.innerHTML"
But I just couldn't solved it

HELPPPP :(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS code to this:

```js
for (let option of options) {
    option.onclick = () => {
        selectText.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

You just need to get the innerHTML of the individual option, no need for the `this`.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qvyyef?file=index.js,index.html

Comment: Thank you sooooo much~~~~!!
My problem is solved QQ

Answer (score 0):

First off, optionsEl is not defined, you need to loop through the options array instead. The following works with a forEach loop:

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
const selectText = document.getElementById("selectText");


options.forEach((option) => {
  option.onclick = () => {
    selectText.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="selectText">All Categories</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="options">A</li>
    <li class="options">B</li>
    <li class="options">C</li>
    <li class="options">D</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for mistyping :(( optionsEl should be options
Thank youuuu!!